# kannada learning - beginner's way

Tags: learning-methods, self-learning, marathi, kannada

I am a native [Marathi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marathi_language) (Maharashtra, India) speaker and I wish to learn [Kannada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kannada).
These 2 languages are totally different except for a few words in common.
To start with, I would like to learn basic conversation-related words, small sentences etc without much grammatical details.

As a beginner, what are the recommended online sources or print texts?
(There are online sources which I could search but not satisfactory).

Comment: Welcome to language learning stack exchange. As is, your question is fairly broad, and it would be better to narrow it down a little. Are you looking for resources, such as textbooks or online courses, for Kannada? What aspect of the language do you want to learn, in particular? Are the languages highly similar?

Comment: @TommiBrander thanks for your reply. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I upvoted and voted to reopen the question. Hopefully an expert will come by and answer; if not, you might want to return later and answer based on the sources you could find.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below link contains some useful phrases for learning kannada and also at the end of page you can find other useful links:

[kannada phrases](https://www.omniglot.com/language/phrases/kannada.php)

This link has more number of basic conversation [kannada phrasebook](https://wikitravel.org/en/Kannada_phrasebook)

Comment: Thanks. Nice resources.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to above answer, you can also learn it from [50 Languages](https://www.50languages.com). You can have their app on mobile if you like.
You can also subscribe to [Kannada TV](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCirKrUfKVP2ebtwEWCObTbw) and [Agurchand Babu Subramanian](https://www.youtube.com/user/agurchand)'s channel for better.

Comment: great resources. Thanks. I think both the answers (yours as well as @karthik are worthy to be accepted. I wish I could do that. I would be rude to un-check the earlier accepted answer now. So pl. "accept my acceptance" :-)